# Reusing colors in highcharts when adding new data

Tags: highcharts

I have a project were we can dynamically add lines to a line chart (by picking from a list outside the chart) and the works fine and it adds each line in the correct color and correct order based on our "colors" list. The problem is that when we remove a line (or several lines), and then add a new line, the color used is the "next in line" from where we left off, not one of the colors we removed.

So for example, our colors are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. The user dynamically makes a chart by adding five lines, so we use colors 1-5. Now the user randomly removes two lines and we are left with colors 1,3,4 for example. Now the user adds two move lines, and the added colors are always 6 and 7, but we would prefer the added colors to be 2 and 5 (since they are no longer being used and they are higher in the priority). Is this possible? We can do a custom solution for sure, but I wanted to see if we were missing anything that's already built.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide code and attempts

Comment: You have to code, it's not provided by Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this options is not possible, but, you can prepare your own function, which will loop for each serie and then set correct color like in the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/gJvde/1/

```
 function setColors(chart){
        var series = chart.series,
                 colors = chart.options.colors,
                 len = series.length-1;

                    if(flag) {
                        $.each(series,function(i,serie){
                            if(i==len) {
                                flag != flag;
                                serie.update({
                                    color: colors[i]
                                },true,true);
                            }
                            else {
                                serie.update({
                                    color: colors[i]
                                },false);
                            }
                        });
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Basically what we decided to do is this: We are assigning the color in the data object when we add the series, and we keep track of the colors we use in another array. Since we already have an array of possible colors, we loop through to find the first unused color every time we add a series.